# Ruby, why did my code for this project not work until i changed this?

Tags: ruby, class, initialization

I am new to coding and I am currently learning Ruby. So i was working on a oyster card project (oyster card is what we use for public transport in London, for those of you unfamiliar with it) and I ran into a problem. So my code used to be:

```
class Oystercard
  attr_reader :balance, :in_journey, :entry_station, :journey, :journey_history

  MAXIMUM_BALANCE = 90
  MINIMUM_CHARGE = 3

  def initialize
    @balance = 0
    @in_journey = false
  end

@journey = Hash.new

  def top_up(amount)
    raise "Cannot top-up more than #{MAXIMUM_BALANCE}" if (@balance + amount) > MAXIMUM_BALANCE

    @balance += amount
  end

  def in_journey?
    !!entry_station
  end

  def touch_in(station)
    raise 'You need to top-up first' if @balance < 1

    @entry_station = station
    @in_journey = true
    @journey[:entry] = @entry_station
    @journey_history.push(journey)
  end

  def touch_out
    deduct(MINIMUM_CHARGE)
    @in_journey = false
    @entry_station = nil
    @journey[:exit] = @entry_station
  end

  private

  def deduct(fare = MINIMUM_CHARGE)
    @balance -= fare
  end
end
```

Now let me explain the problem. When i say IRB and required this file. This is what i did in IRB:

```
oyster = Oystercard.new
oyster.top_up(50)
oyster.touch_in("Paddington")
```

The error i would receive is

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass)
```

The error refers to the last line of the touch_in method. What I am trying to do is make an entry key and make the value, the station that the user inputs. Now i managed to fix this code by adding @journey = Hash.new into the initialize method instead of the line before. So my new code was

```
def initialize
    @balance = 0
    @in_journey = false
    @journey = Hash.new
  end
```

now as soon as i made this change, and made journey into an attribute, my code started to work. However, I am failing to understand why. If you need any more information then let me know and thank you in advance :)

Comment: In the original `@journey` is an instance variable of the class `Oystercard` rather than an instance of  `Oystercard` because it is declared in the scope of the class's lexical declaration (outside of a instance method). When you moved its definition inside the `initialize` method it became an instance variable of the instance of the class and is now accessible in this scope.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, classes are objects. When you write:

```
class Oystercard
  @journey = Hash.new
end
```

You're setting an instance variable *on the class*. Inside the class block, `self` is the `Oystercard` class object.

When you write:

```
class Oystercard
  def initialize
    @journey = Hash.new
  end
end
```

You set the instance variable on each new object [because `Oystercard.new` will allocate a new object and call `initialize` on it](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new). Inside the method, `self` is the new instance.

Comment: thank you. is there ever any benefit of creating an instance variable on the class rather instance?

Comment: @Monkey Yes. Class variables are shared across the class hierarchy. Instance variables are not. They're commonly used in metaprogramming.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira class variables are slightly different than an instance variable of a class. Class variables are defined as `@@variable_name` and are accessible from the instance scope as well as being retained across the class heirarchy  where as Class instance variables (as in this case) belong specifically to a Class and are not accessible from within the instance scope. [See Here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/faq/8/). Class variables are generally frowned upon by the ruby community.